# AWS CDK (Python) -- How can I get CIDR from ipam pool?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, amazon-vpc

I need to create a secondary cidr within an existing vpc and create 2 subnets out of that secondary cidr. I could not figure out how to get cidr block from it so that i can use it for the subnet resources below. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

```
        vpc = ec2.Vpc(self, "myvpc",
            vpc_name= "myvpc",
            ip_addresses= ec2.IpAddresses.aws_ipam_allocation(
                            ipv4_ipam_pool_id=pool_id),
                            ipv4_netmask_length=24
                        ),
            subnet_configuration=subnet_configuration,
            enable_dns_hostnames= True, 
            enable_dns_support= True,
            #max_azs=2,
            availability_zones= [f"{Aws.REGION}a", f"{Aws.REGION}b"],
            nat_gateways = 0
        )


      if secondary_cidr == "True":
        secondary_cidr_block=ec2.CfnVPCCidrBlock(self, "SecondaryCidr",
            vpc_id=vpc.vpc_id,
            ipv4_ipam_pool_id=pool_id,
            ipv4_netmask_length=25,
        )

        priv_subnet_3 = ec2.PrivateSubnet(self, "PrivateSubnet-3",
            availability_zone= us-east-1c,
            cidr_block= ?????,
            vpc_id=vpc.vpc_id,
            map_public_ip_on_launch= False,
        )

        pub_subnet_3 = ec2.PublicSubnet(self, "PublicSubnet-3",
            availability_zone= us-east-1c,
            cidr_block= ?????,
            vpc_id=vpc.vpc_id,
            map_public_ip_on_launch= True,
        )
```

I tried using `secondary_cidr_block.cidr_block` attribute which did not help

Comment: How are you importing your existing vpc? can you add that code too?

Comment: @JatinMehrotra
i am actually creating the vpc within the code, initial vpc has to have 2 public and 2 private subnets. this is the standard configuration, secondary cidr and 3rd subnets should only be added via parameter toggle if the vpc needs additional subnets,

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get this information from just the IPAM Pool ID.

You can either create a custom resource to fetch this information with https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.custom_resources.AwsCustomResource.html.

If you create the IPAM pool in CDK with `CfnIPAMPool`, the provisioned CIDR blocks are available at the [`provisionedCidrs`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ec2.CfnIPAMPool.html#provisionedcidrs-1) prop.